# Simple Commerce Currency

Tags: ecommerce

Even though I have my currency set to CAD my purchases are coming through paypal as USD.  Am I missing something because I cannot figure out why.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" sort="asc" entry_id="21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28"}
{exp:simple_commerce:purchase entry_id="{entry_id}" success="user_main/success" cancel="user_main/index" country_code="CA" currency="CAD"}

       <p><strong>{item_name}</strong> - 
       {if item_type == "purchase"}

< a href="{add_to_cart_url}" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;">Add to Cart</a >

       {/if}

{/exp:simple_commerce:purchase}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Are you send same currency on exp:simple_commerce:purchase tag ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Is your currency set correctly/added in PayPal? Login to PayPal and go to:

***My Account > Profile > My Money > PayPal Balance More Menu > Currencies***

Comment: I was told by the client that it was set correctly.  Maybe I need to have a look myself.

Comment: Double checked myself, made the default currency CAD as well as deleting the USD account that was there.  Still not working, once I deleted the USD account now the user cannot even checkout.